# Dropzone uploadMultiple 100

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I went to upload image more than 20 but my Dropzone response image only 20

```
foreach ($data as $files) {
    $filed = $files->move(public_path('storage/image'));

    $files =$files->getClientOriginalName();
        GallaryDetile::create([
            'filename' => $files,
            "gallary_id"=>$lastId->id       ,
        ]);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMFCX.jpg)

I have been upload more than 20 image but it insert to my laravel only 20
Error : Maximum number of allowable file uploads has been exceeded in in dropzone

Comment: Nothing to do with Laravel: there's a `php.ini` settings `max_file_uploads`

Comment: In `$files->getClientOriginalName()` ... `$files` is not set, you named it `$filed`